# How to extract function from dependent packages and save them locally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js

I am writing a small tool in javascript to store something(as for privKey) into ehtereum contract storage area. For security, I want to strip off all dependent packages and extract the functional interfaces that I need from these dependent packages and save them locally; now there is such a tool to help Can i do it?

Now, I have written a demo and open source in GitHub: https://github.com/seedlist/seedlist-interface

Comment: have you considered git submodules?

Comment: @devdev_dev Yes, I did; What I am worried about is that the dependent package has a backdoor; therefore, it is necessary to extract all dependent functions and put them in the source code of the current project;

Comment: Extract them and make them submodules? or extract them and make your own package?

Comment: @devdev_dev， Yes, Extract them and save into myself package.

Comment: IMO, you should not stress this part too hard. There are a lot of ways you can get security issues with your project, don't focus too hard on things and having "isolated packages" is just the start of the rabbit hole.